# Jquery LocalScroll & ScrollTo - obvious mistake?

Tags: jquery, scrollto, serialscroll

I am working on a project which requires jquery scrollTo plugins from Ariel Flesler: [Plugin-website](http://flesler.blogspot.co.nz/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

I followed the description and also did my research on stackoverflow to be sure.

The following approach is not working, even if it looks right to me.

At this point I guess I am making an obvious mistake which I dont see. **I guess I need some help.**

Here is the code:

**In the head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="(...)/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="(...)/js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="(...)/js/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js"</script>
```

**The jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function( $ ){

var $paneTarget = $('#container');

    $('#down').click(function(){
        $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo( {top:'+=50px',left:'+=0'}, 500 );
    });

});
</script>
```

**The markup:**

```
<div id="container">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<a id="down" href="#">Next item</a>
```

**Note:**

Container - 100px in height

List-Items - 50px in height each

Both have a width of 100%.

I really can't figure out where I am making a mistake here. **What am I missing?**

Comment: Trick question : How many scrolling plugins does it take to move a scrollbar ?

Comment: First of all you have to have the jquery plugin at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for a plugin imho.

```
$(function() {
    var y=0;
    $("#down").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").animate({scrollTop: y+=50}, 1000);
    }) 
})
```

look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsausage/kU2ME/

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you very much for your explanation! Worked great. To make it perfect I would like to achieve the following: After the last item is reached the button scrolles to the top again and the user can go through the list again. Now I dont want you to do my work for me. But can you give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: you must compare scrollTop() and css("height") of the container. if both values are equal then scroll to top again. [here is the fiddle]. hope that helps.(http://jsfiddle.net/UALpA/)

Comment: Hi Dirk, 
wow, thanks for taking time to help me!
Exactely what I was looking for. I stumbled on a problem when I have more than just 4 <li>. Then the container scrolls to top before reaching the last item. Is there a solution for that?